# How to Print this statment in to a txt file

Tags: python, file-io

I am trying to write a txt file but I am getting a `TypeError`.
How do I go about this? Here is my code below:

```
yesterdays_added = f1_set - f2_set
yesterdays_removed = f2_set -f1_set
with open('me{}{}{}.txt'.format(dt.year, '%02d' % dt.month, '%02d' % dt.day), 'w') as out:
    for line in todays:
        if line in yesterdays_added:
            out.write( 'Removed', line.strip())
        elif line in yesterdays_removed:
            out.write ('Added', line.strip())


    for line in yesterdays:
       if line in yesterdays_added:
            out.write ('Removed', line.strip())
        elif line in yesterdays_removed:
            out.write ('Added', line.strip())
```

This is the error I am getting:

```
 out.write ('Added', line.strip())
TypeError: function takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to concatenate those together.

```
out.write("Added "+line.strip()) # Or out.write("Added {}".format(line.strip()))
```

For example,

```
>>> "Added "+"abc\n".strip()
'Added abc'
```

From [The Python Docs](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html)

> f.write(string) writes the contents of string to the file, returning
>   None.

Whenever in doubt, use `help()`.

```
write(...)
    write(str) -> None.  Write string str to file.
```

This says that `write()` only takes in one argument. (Whereas you provide 2, hence the error)

Answer (score 1):

As the error message suggests, `write` takes only one argument. If you want to write two things, make two calls to `write`, or concatenate them with `+`.

Answer (score 0):

**You received this error because the `write` method takes one argument of type `string`.**

The `writelines` method, however, accepts one argument of type `iterable`.

The `writelines` method is the preferred method in this case, unless you would like to format the output string.

**`writelines` example:**

```
lines_to_write = ('Removed', line.strip(),)
open.writelines(lines_to_write)
```

**`write` example:**

```
line_to_write = '{0}...fancy formatting...{1}'.format('Removed', line.strip(),)
open.write(line_to_write)
```

Documentation:
http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#file.write
http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#file.writelines